# Detecting ActiveMQ flow control

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a production system that uses ActiveMQ (5.3.2) to send messages from server A to server B.  A few weeks ago, the system inexplicably started taking 10+ second to send a message.  After a reboot of the producer, the system worked fine.

After investigation, I'm pretty sure this is due to producer flow control.  (I have a fairly standard activemq setup).  The day before this happened (for other reasons) my consumer software had been acting erratically and had even stopped accepting connections for a while.  So I'm guessing this triggered this.  (It does puzzle me that the requests were still being throttled a day later).

Question -- how can I confirm that the requests were being throttled.  I took a heap dump of the server -- is there data in memory I can look for?

Edit: I've found the following:
WireFormatNegotiator.tcpNoDelayEnabled=false for one of three WireFormatNegotiator instances in the memory.  I'm trying to figure out what sets this.

And second (and more important), is there a way I can use JMX to tell if the messages are being throttled? I'd like to set up a Nagios alert to let me know if this happens in the future.  What property should I check for with JMX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [configure your producer client](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html) to throw javax.jms.ResourceAllocationException exceptions which can then be detected/logged, etc.  just set one of the following...

```
<systemUsage>
   <systemUsage sendFailIfNoSpaceAfterTimeout="3000">
   ...OR...   
   <systemUsage sendFailIfNoSpace="true">
```

Comment: useful to know - thanks.  still hoping someone might have more direct answer to my questions.

Comment: Will, this is to detect flow control from a client/monitor perspective.  If you see these errors, then producer flow control has "kicked" in.  If you don't set these, then the send() will just block until the producer can resume.